# Networking Fetch examples missing from documentation

Tags: react-native

I'm following along with the React Native Tutorial and am stuck at the Networking example:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/docs/Networking.md

Up to this point, there's been runnable code and a running example. Suddenly here there is no runnable context for the code samples, nor can I find a single example on the internets of Fetch actually working in React Native.

Just for instance, React Native usually begins something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
```

and ends something like this:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => myApp);
```

Alo, there is usually a `render` function somewhere in there.

I'm just wondering, A) why did the React Native documentation suddenly fall away when it came to Fetch, and B) why are there no working examples available, anywhere?

Thanks & regards!

Comment: Post your code. I remember using fetch a while ago in React-Native. It works the exact same way as it does in JS. Although I did have a problem with async calls, which I can't remember the exact problem but, It's just an api call they didn't shy away from it. Just follow the example in the link you posted. There are millions of `Fetch()` examples online.

Comment: They have examples of using fetch in their docs...http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: If you mean you want to see it being used in context, they have an example here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/Movies and they use fetch in SearchScreen.js